# How to find a rogue Java Web Start jnlf created file on a Mac

Tags: java, macos

I was testing a Java Web Start jnlf file on my Mac (Latest version of OSX)

And a faulty file created a shortcut with the name MyAppName
I stupidly deleted the shortcut then deleted the Application from the Java Cache

From then on I cannot install a shortcut with the name MyAppName, but any other name works

I have hunted all over my Mac's file to find what must be a file storing the shortcut name of MyAppName but cannot find it

Does anyone one know how to find the file?

jnlf snippet:

```
<information>
<title>MyAppName</title>
<vendor>MyVendorName</vendor>
<shortcut online="false" install="false">
<desktop/>
</shortcut>
</information>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sat down today determined o fix this

I give the way to fix it rather than an exact file location, as oracle may move things, again !

1) Use finder then GO (Top menu) with the alt key pressed to allow access to the Library folder

2) Search the library for the name of the Title (MyAppName)

3) It will show in a folder called bundles

4) Check with the Java control file that the MyAppName does not show in the list of installed applications

5) Copy the bundles folder for safety

6) Delete the file that has the name MyAppName

Now the Application can be installed and a shortcut shows for MyAppName

Phil